# Firebird 1.5 : How to get the logarithm of a number

Tags: sql, firebird

We are using Firebird 1.5 database. we need to calculate the logarithm of a number in the query, how can we do that?

I have tried :

```
LOG(3, number_field)
```

but got an error :

```
Error: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
Function unknown
LOG
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 335544569
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: According to this, that's a generic "not defined" error.  Why it's not defined?  I don't know.  http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq261/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firebird 1.5 **Log** function provided via exterbal library **ib_udf.dll**. Check that the file is in the **UDF** subfoler and run a SQL command:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION log 
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DOUBLE PRECISION
    RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION BY VALUE
    ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_log' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf';
```

There is **ib_udf.sql** file in the UDF subfolder which contains commands for declaration of all functions in the library.

Also consider to upgrade your database to **Firebird 2.5** version where **Log** function is built in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use function from ib_udf library.
First you must to declare function. Look to udf/ib_udf.sql file in firebird folder.